# Is mature Multisite

Tags: multisite

I am running a multisite. However, I want to be able to separate certain sites. The only option I see is the "mature" checkbox.

I"m not running mature sites. I wanted to add a "Premium" checkbox, but that seems impossible. So I am marking my premium blogs with the "mature" checkbox.

Is there a "is_mature()" type of function to determine if a multisite is marked mature?

Answer (score 0):

The current WP_Site object is saved as `global $current_blog`, so you can use

```
global $current_blog;
if ( isset( $current_blog ) && $current_blog->mature ) { ... }
```

There's no convenience helper method to fetch this as there is  `get_current_site()` for `$current_site`; there is also `get_site()` which you could use `get_site()->mature` but that doesn't use the already-loaded WP_Site object.

I'd probably store the 'premium' flag in an option, though, which can be per-blog or per-site, but it depends how you want to use it e.g. I doubt you can search for blogs with a given option as easy as you can search for the 'mature' flag.

Comment: When I tried that it returns NULL for both checked and unchecked. When I do a var_dump, I don't see mature in there at all.

Comment: :-( Oops, sorry, I didn't have a multisite to test this on. It looks like it's the global $current_blog then, not $current_site which is what that returns, but there's no helper method to fetch it; alternatively there's `get_site()` but it looks like that does a DB lookup rather than trying the global.